# Android BroadcastReceiver for USB debugging (Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED) enabled/disable

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my project, for security reasons, I need to be aware if USB debugging is enabled on device in order to disable some sensitive functionality.

I am able to figure out if it is currently enabled or not by doing the following check:
`Settings.Global.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0) == 1`

But I also need to know when it is being enabled/disabled reactively. So I need to have a broadcast receiver which listens for this setting change events.

I searched the web but did not even found any question about this and even not found if Android even has such a broadcast receiver or not.

So any information related to this topic would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the answer to this question myself.

Actually there is **no** BroadcastReceiver for tracking changes of USB debugging setting. However, because Android settings are mostly exposed through `ContentProvider` Api we can register a `ContentObserver` on any data exposed through `ContentProvider`.

Below is the code snipped that did the work for me for USB debugging, but with slightly changes this can work to listen changes for almost any other Android setting change:

```
class UsbDebuggingStateObserver private constructor(val context: Context, handler: Handler, val changeListener: (Boolean) -> Unit) : ContentObserver(handler) {
    
    private var lastEnabled: Boolean = isUsbDebuggingEnabled()

    override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
        val nowEnabled = isUsbDebuggingEnabled()
        if(lastEnabled != nowEnabled){
            lastEnabled = nowEnabled
            changeListener.invoke(nowEnabled)
        }
    }

    fun isUsbDebuggingEnabled(): Boolean {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0) == 1
    }

    companion object {
        fun startObserving(context: Context, changeListener: (Boolean) -> Unit){
            val observer = UsbDebuggingStateObserver(context, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()), changeListener)
            context.contentResolver
                .registerContentObserver(Settings.Global.getUriFor(Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED), true, observer)
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage is as follows:

```
UsbDebuggingStateObserver.startObserving(app) { enabled -> 
   // your code here
}
```

**Note**, I needed to observe this setting through whole lifetime of my application, so I start observing in `onCreate` of my application class and never stop. If you have different situation you might need also to unregister the observer.