# Detect if user have usb debugging mode enable and prevent app using until it is disable on React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I'm using ReactNative. I want to know if there is a way to programmatically detect if usb debugging mode is enabled and prevent user from using app if it does.

I try searching around for document about this on react native but nothing useful comes up

Comment: Check jail-monkey library, it may help you

Answer (score 0):

To call Android Native APIs from the ReactNative code, you have to create Android Native Module in your project and create an API in the Java/Kotlin side to read the Global Setting for `ADB_ENABLED`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#ADB_ENABLED
using something like this
`Settings.Global.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0)`

Ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Ref: [Android BroadcastReceiver for USB debugging (Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED) enabled/disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69141289/android-broadcastreceiver-for-usb-debugging-settings-global-adb-enabled-enable)